# Probability of the intersection of sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space. Suppose that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$. Is it possible to conclude that

$$P(C\cap A\cap B)=P(C\cap A)\quad\forall C\in F$$ 
? Thank you very much!:)

Comment: Do you know the [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle)?

Comment: Yes because then $A \cap B = A$, i.e. $A = B$.

Comment: $A \cap B = A \Rightarrow P(A \cap B) = P(A)$, not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Since $C\cap A\cap B^\complement\subseteq A\cap B^\complement$, therefore $\mathsf P(C\cap A\cap B^\complement)\leqslant \mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement)$.

Now, by the Additivity of Probabilities of Disjoint Events (or the Law of Total Probability: $$\mathsf P(C\cap A)=\mathsf P(C\cap A\cap B)+\mathsf P(C\cap A\cap B^\complement)\\\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement)\qquad$$

So, if $\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(A\cap B)$, then ...

Answer (score 0):

$$P(C\cap B\cap A)\leq P(C \cap A) =P(C \cap A \cap B)+P(C \cap A \cap B^{c})$$ by additivity (where $B^{c}$ is the complement of $B$).

Now $$P(C \cap A \cap B^{c}) \leq P( A \cap (A \cap B)^{c})=P(A)-P(A \cap B)=0.$$ Hence we get  $$P(C\cap B\cap A) \leq P(A \cap C)\leq P(C\cap B\cap A)+0=P(C\cap B\cap A)$$ which proves the result.

Answer (score 0):

$$A = (A\cap B) \cup (A\cap B^c). (A\cap B) \cap (A\cap B^c) = \emptyset $$

$$\therefore P(A\cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A\cap B) = 0$$

$$A\cap C = (A\cap B\cap C) \cup (A\cap B^C \cap C).\\ A\cap B^c \cap C \subseteq A\cap B^c \\\therefore P(A\cap B^c \cap C) \le P(A \cap B^c) \therefore P(A\cap B^c \cap C) = 0$$

$$\therefore P(A\cap C) = P(A\cap B\cap C) - 0 = P(A\cap B\cap C) \space\space\space\space\space\square$$